# MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server on first connect MongoNetworkError: connection 4 to mongodb.net:27017 closed

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, react-native, mongodb-query

MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [cluster6-shard-00-02.mongodb.net:27017] on first connect [MongoNetworkError: connection 4 to
cluster6-shard-00-02.mongodb.net:27017 closed
at TLSSocket.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search my ip address in your system/laptop
it will show your internet connected ip address add that in go to network access add you ip address there